# Can NDB objects be modeled to compose well with protorpc Messages

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, endpoints-proto-datastore

I'm trying out Google App Engine's Endpoints service on an existing GAE project.  My existing application has several NDB classes which I'd basically just like to spit out as JSON through the Endpoints framework.  I'm trying to find the best DRY way of doing this - it's not clear how Endpoints was designed to expose an NDB class through a protorpc Message.  Which I would think is the most common use case.

Comment: You should just be able to replace `MyClass(ndb.Model)` with `MyClass(EndpointsModel)` and have no issues. `EndpointsModel` is a direct subclass of `ndb.Model`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat.  [endpoints-proto-datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore) was the answer from Google.  The library works very well when the Message and the NDB model is one-to-one. But it quickly became challenging when I worked on a composite NDB models.

It seems the library is no longer maintained as the author left Google.

Comment: I still maintain it :)